# My python code still runs even though the if statement is false

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

```
bool_value=True

if (not bool_value==False):
  print("Hello world")
```

i dont know why it still printing hello world even though i have set bool_value to false by using not keyword .It shouldnt print anything when the condition is false right?

Comment: `not bool_value==False` is equivalent to `bool_value!=False` and `True!=False`.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is true.

First, it evaluates bool_value == False, which will return a False value, then it will negate it (with the "not" keyword), which will finally return True.

Comment: Daniel, I believe you have the precedence wrong. The first thing evaluated is `bool_value == False`, which gives false, the `not`ting that gives you true.

Answer (score 1):

```
not bool_value==False
```

evaluates as `not (bool_value == False)`. Since `bool_value` is true, it therefore becomes (in sequence):

```
not (bool_value == False)
not (True == False)
not (False)
True
```

You could also establish this if you simply put a:

```
print(not bool_value==False)
```

before your `if` statement.

So, no, the condition is *not* true<sup>(a)</sup>. If you want to do something only when a conditional variable is false, the correct way is simply:

```
if not conditional_variable:
    do_something()
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Or, in a similar vein as your original expression, "not not false" :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have written `if not`
this reverses your condition and says if it is not false then run this code meaning that all you need to do is remove the `not` from the if loop
so like this

```
bool_value=True

if bool_value==False:
  print("Hello world")
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be to use `not bool_value` instead.